# Fetching a part from a string

Tags: regex

I have a string like:
Input-   "08.08(1).jpg"
I want output :
   08.08(1)
Can anyone help me out to solve this using REGEX in java.

Comment: straightforward if you put some effort in...

Answer (score 1):

Use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` methods.

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(".") - 1)
```

Comment: Actually i have a string like "a/b/c/d.e.f"   i want output like" d.e"   for that i am using regex in eclipse.  So can you please help me for this.

Comment: @Ananya `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, str.lastIndexOf(".") - 1)`

Comment: @Ananya : glad to help :)